# Using WH_JOURNALRECORD and cancel does seem to return the WM_CANCELJOURNAL

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, setwindowshookex

I'm using C# and I've got the program successfully recording the journal messages using `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_JOURNALRECORD`.

My problem comes when it's time to stop. The docs show that if the user pressed CTRL-ESC or CTRL-ALT-DELETE a `WM_CANCELJOURNAL` message will be posted that I can watch to know when to stop. My application gets unhooked but I never seem to get a `WM_CANCELJOURNAL`.

I have two hooks setup. One hook to do the Journal Record and one to check for the cancel message:

```
IntPtr hinstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]);

JournalRecordProcedure = JournalRecordProc;
journalHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_JOURNALRECORD, JournalRecordProcedure, hinstance, 0);

GetMessageProcedure = GetMessageProc;
messageHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMessageProcedure, hinstance, 0); 


------

public static int JournalRecordProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(journalHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    EventMsgStruct msg = (EventMsgStruct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof (EventMsgStruct));

    script.Add(msg); //just a quick way to record for now

    return CallNextHookEx(journalHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

public static int GetMessageProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{

    //it comes here but how do I test if it's WM_CANCELJOURNAL ??
    //code always seems to be equal to zero.. I must be missing something


    return CallNextHookEx(journalHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're referring to this section in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644983.aspx):

> This role as a signal to stop journal recording means that a CTRL+BREAK key combination cannot itself be recorded. Since the CTRL+C key combination has no such role as a journaling signal, it can be recorded. There are two other key combinations that cannot be recorded: CTRL+ESC and CTRL+ALT+DEL. Those two key combinations cause the system to stop all journaling activities (record or playback), remove all journaling hooks, and post a `WM_CANCELJOURNAL` message to the journaling application.

The problem is that the [`WM_CANCELJOURNAL` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644971.aspx) is **not** sent to the callback function you installed with `SetWindowsHookEx`. But unlike other `WM_*` messages, it is also not meant to be processed by a window procedure (`WndProc` in WinForms) because it is posted to the message queue of the *thread* and is not associated with any particular window.

Rather, the documentation advises that one must process it within an application's main loop or using a [`WH_GETMESSAGE` hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#whgetmessagehook):

> This message does not return a value. It is meant to be processed from within an application's main loop or a GetMessage hook procedure, not from a window procedure.
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> The `WM_CANCELJOURNAL` message has a `NULL` window handle, therefore it cannot be dispatched to a window procedure. There are two ways for an application to see a `WM_CANCELJOURNAL` message: If the application is running in its own main loop, it must catch the message between its call to `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` and its call to `DispatchMessage`. If the application is not running in its own main loop, it must set a `GetMsgProc` hook procedure (through a call to `SetWindowsHookEx` specifying the `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook type) that watches for the message.

In managed WinForms code, you obviously don't have any access to or control over the application's main loop. I'm not sure if [adding a message filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) to your application will let you handle this message or not: I haven't tried it. If it will, that's probably the route you want to take, considering the alternative, which is to install a *second* hook, `WH_GETMESSAGE`, and then in that hook procedure, listen for the `WM_CANCELJOURNAL` message.

---

**Update:**

In the [`GetMessageProc` callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981.aspx), the `code` parameter just tells you whether the hook procedure should process the message. Virtually all of the time, it's going to be 0, which is equivalent to the symbolic constant `HC_ACTION`. If the `code` parameter is less than 0, the hook procedure should simply call the `CallNextHookEx` function without performing any further processing. That's basically the exact same thing you did for the `JournalRecordProc` callback function.

The window message is going to be found in a [`MSG` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx), a pointer to which is passed to the callback function as the `lParam` parameter. But that's Win32 stuff. Don't mess with raw pointers in .NET, let the P/Invoke marshaler handle all of that dirty stuff for you. The native `MSG` structure is equivalent to the managed [`System.Windows.Forms.Message` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.aspx) (the same thing used by the `WndProc` method), so if you declare your `GetMessageProc` callback function like this, things will be much simpler:

```
public delegate int GetMessageProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, ref Message lParam);
```

Then, the windows message is found as the [`Msg` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.msg.aspx) of the `Message` structure. That's the value you want to compare against `WM_CANCELJOURNAL`:

```
public static int GetMessageProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, ref Message lParam)
{
    if (code >= 0)
    {
        if (lParam.Msg == WM_CANCELJOURNAL)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(messageHook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
}
```

Note that in order for the above call to `CallNextHookEx` to work, you'll also have to provide an overloaded definition of the `CallNextHookEx` function that matches the signature of your `GetMessageProc` callback function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int nCode,
                                        IntPtr wParam, ref Message lParam);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The application is not able to install the hook via the Application object, so my only recourse is to create another global hook which is the method I've been trying, but without success.

Comment: @Kelly: You know that to install another hook you need to call `SetWindowsHookEx` a second time, this time with the `WH_GETMESSAGE` constant, and then specify a different hook procedure? Update your question with the code you've been trying and I'll try to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: I updated the question to give more detail. I am doing two hooks. The first to do the journal record and the second just to listen for the cancel message. The hook works and I see messages in the GetMessageProc but I never see anything I can identify as a WM_CANCELJOURNAL. Any ideas how I test for it?

Comment: @Kelly: You're checking `code` for the value, but that's the same as `nCode` in your first hook callback procedure. The message is passed as a member of the struct passed as a pointer in `lParam`. Sorry, it gets complicated. I've updated my answer with code that should work.